# android fragmenttransaction error- cannot resolve method add(int,com.mypackage.SampleFragmentActivity)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm  getting an error while trying to add a fragment to my main activity.
Error showing is cannot resolve method add(int,com.mypackage.SampleFragmentActivity)

Main Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;

public class MultiPlayerActivity extends Activity {
*
*
*
   public void manageServerConnection(BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket){
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sample);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            SampleFragmentActivity samplefragment = new SampleFragmentActivity();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentHolder, samplefragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
*
*
}
```

SampleFragmentActivity:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class SampleFragmentActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public SampleFragmentActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sample_fragment, container, false);

        EditText ed = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button sendButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

        return view;
    }


}
```

fargmentSample.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentHolder"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_sample_fargment.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.mypackagename.SampleFragmentActivityFragment">

<TextView android:text="Enter Text" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView12" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView12" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me in resolving the error. I had tried changing import to  `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` but was still getting error

Comment: What is SampleFragmentActivity. Is it a fragment or activity?

Comment: @chandrakanth, SampleFragmentActivity is the fragment which i need to open inside main activity which is MultiplayerActivity.

Comment: Thanks for posting this - you helped me track down the issue in my setup. While I was importing the correct version of the Fragment in my activity (`android.app.Fragment`), I was importing the support version in my fragment class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;

public class MultiPlayerActivity extends Activity {
*
*
*
   public void manageServerConnection(BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket){
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sample);
            Fragment fragment = new SampleFragmentActivityFragment();
            FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
            frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment).commit();
        }
*
*
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change your Activity to FragmentActivity and try this code..

```
SampleFragmentActivity fragment=new SampleFragmentActivity();
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment).commit();
```